# I am having trouble adjusting the Firebase rules as I want

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The first additional node in my Messages table is biletId, because messages are directed through the corresponding ticket. The second node is the messageId itself. However, when writing rules, I am unable to access the data in the Messages table.

[image]

[image]

[image]
I have tried to edit the rules as like this, but it still doesn't work, and even if I set the read permission to true, I still cannot read the data from the database with this codes but However, if I set the read part to true in the above code block, I can read the data. The problem there is that I cannot access the values inside the data.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your security rules, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also keep in mind that security rules do nothing on their own, but only become active once you execute against them. So edit your code to also include the [minimal code with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and in that code show that it meets the requirements of your rules (e.g. check that a user is signed in, and has the UID that your rules expect).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.